# bitcoind: why sendmany allows only double-precision floating point numbers?

Tags: bitcoind

I am switching from electrum to bitcoind. On `electrum` is function `paytomany` which accept usual bitcoin amounts like `0.0001`. But why method sendtomany accept only double-precision floating point numbers? Maybe there is another option for that purpose and I just missed it?

Comment: What is the difference between `0.0001` and "floating point numbers"? The Bitcoin Core RPC accepts amounts either as strings or as numbers (JSON has no concept of floating-point or double precision; everything is just a "number").

Comment: it only allow number like 0.02, 0.01 etc, only two digits

Comment: That's just wrong. Any valid amount can be provided in the JSON-RPC interface or the GUI (meaning up to 8 digits after the dot, because BTC can be subsidivided into 10^8 units).